# Change backgroundPosition of image depending on if

Tags: javascript

```
$(".addon-checkbox").style.backgroundPosition = 
     if(localStorage["__Enable__"+__addons[i]] != "yes") "0 -50px";
     else "0 0";
```

How make this code correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A jQuery object has no `style` property ?

```
var bg = localStorage["__Enable__"+__addons[i]] != "yes" ? "0 -50px" : "0 0";

$(".addon-checkbox").css('background-position', bg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
$(".addon-checkbox").get().style.backgroundPosition = 
     (localStorage["__Enable__"+__addons[i]] != "yes") ? "0 -50px" : "0 0";
```

Comment: That would be $(".addon-checkbox").get().style

Comment: You're right, I didn't bother testing it :) now it's fixed.